# Changing date format in Python from YYYY:Q1 to YYYY/MM

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

i have a dataset that uses the format '1998:q1' however this does not recognise as a temporal variable in vega lite. Is there a way to convert this in to the format 1998/01 and repeat this for the whole dataset?

[link to dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GeorgeRobbin/GeorgeRobbin.github.io/main/Book1.csv)

Current format:

| Date |
| --- |
| 1998:Q1 |
| 1998:Q2 |

Desired format:

| Date |
| --- |
| 1998/01 |
| 1998/04 |

tried

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format = '%Y%M')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) with `freq='Q'`, then [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'].str.replace(':', '-'), freq='Q').strftime('%Y/%m')
```

Output:

```
        Date    Real_HPI    HPI_Rent  HPI_Income
0    1982/03   56.915399   73.676471   91.525857
1    1982/06   57.617379   73.555343   92.184294
2    1982/09   55.792959   70.956878   89.093476
3    1982/12   57.685409   74.935861   92.330045
4    1983/03   58.654319   75.943255   93.027588
..       ...         ...         ...         ...
157  2021/06  110.749697   94.707024   87.563696
158  2021/09  115.405297   99.181098   92.331803
159  2021/12  117.743697  101.504486   95.433863
160  2022/03  120.107097  103.799870   99.858203
161  2022/06  125.751597  108.749527  104.841177

[162 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, you can use apply() like below -

```
def fun(var):
    l = var.split(":")
    if l[1] == "Q1":
        return l[0]+"/01"
    elif l[1] == "Q2":
        return l[0]+"/04"
    elif l[1] == "Q3":
        return l[0]+"/07"
    elif l[1] == "Q4":
        return l[0]+"/10"

df['new_date'] = df['Date'].apply(fun)
```

Sample output -

[image: Sample output]